# Failing Salesforce Queue

Tags: apex, governorlimits, asynchronous, queue

I am rearchitecting some apex code that I have been handed. I updated an @future method to use the Queueable interface, because as it turns out the method was being called as part of trigger that was occasionally being called in a batchable context. Switching to Queueable is compatible with batchable apex.

However, in doing this, I discovered a loop in the previously @future method; this loop was looping over all the records that triggered the process; in fact, it was ACTUALLY looping over all the the RELATED RECORDS of a given object of the records that triggered the process. This can add up significantly, because if 7 or 8 records are in the batch, looping over these is no big deal. However, if each records also has 7 or 8 related records, we are looping over many more records than just what was in the original batch.

This isn't usually a problem, because looping over several hundred records is fine, depending on what happens in the loop. And that is the catch. I found a function call in the loop (still no big deal). However, hidden in the function call was a soql query. Surprise. To amplify this issue, the loop actually refers to this function SEVERAL times. Needless to say, I am discovering that the SOQL limitation is quickly maxing out.

So my current task is to rewrite this code to not include a soql query in a loop. However, I do have one perplexing thing going on; if I pull up the apex jobs in setup in salesforce, I notice some odd behavior; the process doesn't just fail once, like I would expect. It actually fails twice, and then SUCCEEDS after that. I would expect the process to fail once, then the transaction to revert.

Is there some sort of auto retry in salesforce queues, maybe that picks up where it left off or something? There is nothing in the code I am looking at that attempts a retry, so I am just very confused why it not only fails multiple times, but then succeeds. Any ideas? I cannot figure out why this queueable transaction would fail with a governor limit, and yet still succeed.

Its a pretty simple function, just a loop and function calls really. No retry logic or anything.

```
public static void myFunction(Set<Id> accIds) {
     // Select all records where relatedId IN :accIds
     // Loop over records
          // Function Call in Loop - includes soql query
     //Update
}
```

Comment: do you have a transaction finalizer on your queueable that does a retry?

Comment: I do not, which is puzzling...is this the only option for post transaction processing?

Comment: What makes you think all three jobs are kicked off by one transaction, rather than one job each from three separate transactions?

Comment: Interesting thought; however, this does not answer my concern that the job should not be passing at all, seeing as how the 'successful' job certainly should have encountered the same soql issue.